# How do I launch animationdrawable onTouch?

Tags: android, android-animation, ontouch, animationdrawable

I have cat animation jumping, it has 5 drawables, i want to touch the cat and make it jump.

if android oneshot="false", after touching the cat it keeps jumping 
forever.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat1" android:duration="250"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat2" android:duration="250"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat3" android:duration="250"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat4" android:duration="250"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat5" android:duration="250"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/cat1" android:duration="250"></item>
```

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page5);
    cat_jump = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cat_jump);
    cat_jump.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat_jumping_animation);

    final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) cat_jump.getBackground();

    cat_jump.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try View.OnTouchListener : http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html and ref : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html.

Answer (score 1):

create this oncreate

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cat_jump);
    AnimationDrawable aw = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();

    aw.stop();
    aw.start();
```

then,

```
public void Start() {
    aw.stop();
    aw.start();
}

public void Stop() {
    aw.stop();

}
```

Comment: @Mohamad, sorry did not get it - how Start() is called?